# How to add location specific urls to sitemap?

Tags: localization, seo, sitemap

I want to add a few urls to a sitemap that are targeted for a specific location **only**, but I cannot figure out how to do this.
There's a great deal of documentation about how to add location specific *alternatives* to the sitemap (with [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en&ref_topic=2370587)), but I cannot find any resources on how to add pages for a specific location only. My initial thought was to just omit the `<loc>` value and only specify the `<xhtml:link rel="alternate">` tags, but according to the [specification](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) `<loc>` is required.

So, what is the proper way to add location specific urls to a asitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark 1**

Please note that there are other search engines than Google which accept sitemaps. The `xmlns:xhtml` namespace which is needed for the `hreflang` attribute in sitemaps is a sitemap extension which might not be accepted by all search engines. The sitemap specification does not mention that attribute. Therefore, I wouldn't use it anyway.

**Remark 2**

In your question, you are using the terms `location` and `language`. I am not sure what exactly you mean by `location`. But please note that there is a difference between a language to be targeted, a certain locale of a language to be targeted and the *region* to be targeted (which might have nothing to do with the language or locale).

This subject is slightly off-topic, so I won't give a lengthy citation here. The section "Supported language values" from the page I have linked below has some information about it.

**Possible solution**

Even if you care only about Google, you just might not be able to do what you want - at a first glance, I as well couldn't find any direct answer to your question.

But fortunately, you don't need to stuff that kind of meta information into sitemaps. Instead, you can add it to the `<head>` of your HTML files. From [this document](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) (emphasis mine):

> If you have multiple language versions of a URL, each language page
>   should identify different language versions, **>>>>>> including itself <<<<<<**.  For
>   example, if your site provides content in French, English, and
>   Spanish, **the Spanish version must include a rel="alternate"
>   hreflang="x" link >>>>>> *for itself* <<<<<< in addition to links to
>   the French and English versions**. Similarly, the English and French
>   versions must each include **>>>>>> the same <<<<<<** references to the
>   French, English, and Spanish versions.

So it is clear that a page not only can, but even *should* contain a `rel="alternate" hreflang="<insert uri of page itself here>"` link.

This might be worrying because no reasonable person would call a certain, given page an alternative to that same page; on the other hand, it makes sense and simplifies things if all of those `<link>` entries have the same form. That way, you could insert exactly the same bunch of `<link>`s into every page (e.g. by copy-and-paste or by letting it do some tool or script).

The key point here is that this works whether or not a page has something a reasonable person could call an "alternate". If it hasn't, the page is the only "alternate" of itself, so just add the one, appropriate `<link>` to its `<head>`.

Now, coming back to your problem, you could

- remove all `xhtml:link` elements and the `xmlns:xhtml` namespace from the sitemap

- in every page, add exactly the `hreflang` links which are needed; notably, in every page which only should target one language, just add one link (with the appropriate `hreflang` attribute) which references that page itself.

**Very unsafe reasoning**

If you still would like to solve your problem just using sitemap files, you eventually could conclude (by analogy) that including just one alternate link per `<loc>` will produce the same results as if you would have that `<link>` in the respective page's `<head>`.

IMHO, this conclusion is dangerous, and I have absolutely no clue if it is valid. But you could try it with one new test page which won't disturb your production web site and see how it works.

I wouldn't go that way for the reasons mentioned above, though.

Comment: Alternates in the website aren't mutually exclusive to putting them in sitemap, and there are compelling reasons to use both (e.g. putting alternates in sitemap allows tools to reason about internationalization without crawling, and having them in the HTML allows crawler to discover alternatives even if they're not part of the sitemap). In my case I actually already use both, precisely for that reason. Your proposed solution unfortunataly doesn't extend to sitemaps: sitemaps don't have an `x-default` alternate that can be omitted, but instead a *required* `loc` element.

Comment: Well, I am seeing things a little bit more relaxed. I am just assuming that the sitemap will make Google crawl the URLs, and this is the moment when Google can make it decisions. But of course, I can see your point, and therefore I had the section "Very unsafe reasoning" in my answer. That section proposes exactly what you are doing now according to your own answer.

Comment: In practice Google won't crawl all the urls it finds in the sitemap though (unless you're having only a couple of dozens of pages). I completely misread your last part yesterday (let's blame it on being early monday morning), but you're right. I'm sorry for already giving away the bounty to the other answer, but I've at least still marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: No problem regarding the badge, and thanks for accepting the answer. One additional question (because you comment has slightly worried me): Will Google show a page in the search results if the page is in the sitemap, but has not been crawled (yet)? I strongly doubt that (for example, what snippet should it use, and what title, and so on?). Thus, based on the sitemap, Google may know that there is an alternate page, but that won't help you because it won't show up in the search results anyway. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I don't think Google will show a page in the search result if it hasn't been crawled yet, but there is a good chance that they use the information in the sitemap to prioritize the pages to crawl. E.g. it wouldn't surprise me if Google prioritizes crawling your localized pages based on the actual traffic to your page. So if most of your (search) traffic is in German then it might prioritize German entries over (e.g.) Spanish entries.

Comment: I see. This is an interesting point. Thanks for bringing it up. I am not completely sure if this is what I would want in every case, though. I will have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: Yes**. It is possible to add *few* urls/`<loc>` that are targeted **ONLY** for a specific geographic location.

**How?**

Create a locale specific entry including a single alternate for the locale itself. I.e. instead of the usual:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
  <xhtml:link 
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="en"
               href="http://www.example.com/" />
  <xhtml:link 
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/" />
</url>
```

**Do:**

```
<url>
  <loc>http://example.com/schweiz-deutsch/</loc>
  <xhtml:link 
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="de-ch"
               href="http://www.example.com/schweiz-deutsch/" />
</url>
```

This seems to be enough for Google to infer that the page is only intended for de-ch users and doesn't have an alternative representation in any other language.

It is also possible to indicate to google that your website(*all urls*) are for a particular country via [GeoTargeting](https://searchenginewatch.com/sew/how-to/2232347/a-simple-guide-to-using-rel-alternate-hreflang-x)

**References**:

- [Regional URLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427.aspx#Localizing%20the%20URL%20Property%20in%20a%20Site%20Map)
- [Localizing URL property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427.aspx#Localizing%20the%20URL%20Property%20in%20a%20Site%20Map)
- [International Targeting](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399?hl=en)

Comment: After reading your resources and much more testing it *does* seem to be possible, see my own answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42766588/532901). Since you're answer was the one that got me on the right track I'll award the bounty to you.

Comment: okay, yes, then I shall update my answer to avoid misleading others.